# How do I create a tensorflow gpu docker container with data-science library support?

Tags: python, docker, tensorflow

I have managed to create and run a tensorflow container with gpu support, and managed to run simple python scripts that only use tensorflow. But I would like to be able to use other librarys such as openCV, PIL, etc..

I've seen tutorials for setting up 'datascience' containers, but none with GPU acceleration. Could somone provide me with the code needed for the Dockerfile that will build a container with tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-gpu as its base and allow me to cut and paste librarys as required.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A minimal Dockerfile that builds upon `tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-gpu` and installs some custom debian and python packages on top of it could look like so:

```
# Install custom debian packages you need
# e.g. python 3 pip
RUN apt update && apt install -y -q python3-pip

# Install custom python 3 packages
RUN pip3 install opencv-python pillow
```

Use `RUN pip` if you want to work with (deprecated) python 2.

You can build the Dockerfile via:

```
docker build -t my-tf-gpu .
```